# Which countries have the same international importance, influence and power as Sweden?

Tags: economy, europe, geopolitics, power, gdp

Sweden is not a superpower at all and it's not a country with a high level of influence (such as Russia or China). However, it has a relatively large GDP for its population and it's known that Sweden is one of the most developed countries in the world. Besides, it has been described as the most important country of the Nordic Countries, due to its population (which is the largest among these countries) and its historic relative importance.

I was wondering what countries (preferably inside Europe) can compare to Sweden in terms of international influence, power and importance. I mean, countries with not a very high level of these characteristics but with a relatively big amount of them considering its size and population.

I was thinking about the Netherlands, Poland, Norway, Greece, and possibly Portugal Romania and Finland.

The Netherlands, because it is the most important country of the "Benelux" and for its size, it has a relatively large importance. It has even been described as the "Most important nation of all the small nations".

Poland because it has the second biggest economy of the countries in the "Slavonic" world (after Russia) and it is one of the most developed ones.

Norway because, despite its relatively small population, it has valuable resources (such as petroleum) and it is one of the richest and well developed countries in the world.

Greece because it has traditionally been the most well developed country in the zone of the Balkans (although sometimes Greece is excluded when we talk about this region) if not the most developed, despite its profound economic crisis. Until recently, it had the biggest economy in the zone, but it was surpassed by Romania, if we include Romania (or at least parts of the Romanian territory) to be in the Balkans. Also, ancient Greek culture had an enormous impact and influence in the western civilization.

About Portugal, Finland and Romania I am not sure (for example, Romania has a relatively high GDP for its local region, but it is still not as well developed as other countries with those levels of GDP).

Therefore, is this short "list" is correct? Would you remove some countries of this list? Would you add some countries to this list?

Comment: There is no reasonably objective measure of "importance", so I don't think there is a possible answer.  Perhaps if you explained what the purpose of the question is....Why Sweden?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your question assumes that there is an overall measure of "importance." But importance varies from context to context.

- Sweden used to be a neutral country during the Cold War, neither part of NATO nor part of the Warsaw Pact. This gave it **diplomatic** importance. Names like Dag Hammarskjöld and Olof Palme are still remembered. The reputation exists even today.
- Percentage-wise, Sweden is a top contributor of **foreign aid**. That is recognized.
- Sweden is an active participant in peacekeeping operations.
- Sweden is the [protecting power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protecting_power#Current_mandates) for many other countries in North Korea, a diplomatic service which earns recognition.
- Sweden has only a limited capacity for power projection, but that is true of most regional or mid-sized powers.
- Sweden is an **EU member** and has some influence through their voice in that organization.

I think your line of reasoning is wrong. Sweden is more powerful in fields of policy where it can build alliances, it is less powerful in fields where it stands alone. That is not a function of deployable brigades, or GDP, or population, or number of embassies abroad.